# How to use COUNTA and COUNTIF together in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

[image: Screenshot of mock up]

I have a datasheet that contains registration information.  I am trying to count rows in column C, D and E which lists the outcome of the consultation (can contain any kind of text), where the corresponding rows in column B have a specific text (the country they are from).
Eg.
A company has an awareness and registration drive. I need to capture the number of people who registered, the number who are undecided and the number who chose not to register.  I need to capture the above information broken down by country (Eg. How many from Canada chose not to register? How many from the USA are undecided? How many from Jamaica registered? Those three countries are the focus but I also need to reflect how many from "other countries" either registered, are undecided or chose not to register. There are several registration hubs, the column for those who register lists the registration hub, the "undecided" and "chose not to register" columns list the reason given.

I tried using COUNTA and IF Eg. (COUNTA(C:C, IF(B:B,"Canada").  I have tried every version of COUNTA and IF, AND, COUNTIFS, COUNTA and SUMPRODUCT(ISTEXT) etc that I could come up with but I keep getting errors.

Comment: why would you need COUNTA?: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B:B,{"Canada","USA","Jamaica"}))`

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I realise from your answer that I did not ask the question properly.  I will re-phrase in better detail as follows: I have a datasheet of people who signed up for a consultation.  Column A - Name, Column B - Location, Column C - Chose to Register, Column D - Undecided, Column E - Chose not to Register.  I am trying to extract the country and decision. Eg, How many from Canada chose to register/undecided/ chose not to register?  How many from the USA, how many from Jamaica etc.. Also, how many chose to register/undecided/not register but are not from Canada, USA or Jamaica?

Comment: please mock up an example and expected output of that example.  Your description is hard to visualize.

Comment: Please [edit] the post with the clarifications and it would really help if you would create and provide test data in tabular form and expected output.  Do all that in the original post.

Comment: @ScottCraner I made the edit in the original post and added a screenshot for clarity.

Comment: do something like: `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$11="Canada")*($C$3:$C$11<>""))` as for the all others you would exclude them by adding Booleans that ar like `($B$3:$B$11<>"Canada")` and multiply them all together.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you!!! These worked perfectly! You are a life saver!